# How to prevent users to visit R shiny app through URL directly?

Tags: r, url, shiny

I have a parent website, which has hundreds of users with their password and account registered already.

[image]

I have many R shiny apps on the site and I don't want users to visit apps through URL directly. How can I achieve this (maybe bind the parent site's url to shiny app)? A minimal shiny app example as below, thanks in advance:

```
n <- 200
# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', n),
  plotOutput('plot')
)

# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(runif(input$n))
  })
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Perhaps this is less a programming question and more about server configuration. However, if you a using the free shiny server you could migrate to shinyproxy (https://www.shinyproxy.io/) to take advantage of the open source authentication that project offers

Comment: You can use the `nginx` and configure the proxies accordingly. Example here https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213733868-Running-Shiny-Server-with-a-Proxy

Comment: @PorkChop:  I''m not familiar with nginx, do I have to add all users' password and account in `ginx.conf` manually?  Or is it possible to add parent site's url in `ginx.conf`? Thanks.

Comment: Dean Created a nice article how setup shiny server on ubuntu and he has also setup the nginx on top,  have a read https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-shiny-server-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @PorkChop: Thanks for your reply. Does `example.com` mentioned in article equal to my **parent site's url**? Thanks.

Comment: yes, you dont really need the url until the end or at all. First work with numeric IP address where you should be able access the apps via 3838, then you can proxy that with `nginx` as per example.